# How can I write this formula?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

I wrote this it is the first equation it gives me an error I don't understand why

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
$$ maxdd(t) = max\limits_{0\leq\tau\leqt} dd(\tau)$$`
\end{document}
```

Comment: The  index of \max should end in `\tau\leq t}` (with a space). Unrelated: you shouldn't use the plain TeX construct `$$ $$` but the LaTeX one `\[   \]`., to have a better vertical spacing.

Comment: You should also remove an unnecessary accent  `'` at the end of your formula.

Comment: As for the "why", `\limits` are only used with operator names (either those from the package or the ones declared with `\DeclareMathOperator*`)

Answer (score 4):

You have several issues in your code:

1. Use `\[` and `\]` for mathematical mode instead `$$`.
2. The operater for max in written as `\max`, for example `\max dd(t)` or `\max\limits`.
3. After an operator like `\leq` you need a blank like `\leq t` instead your wrong `\leqt`

So with the complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumerate}


\begin{document}
\[ \max dd(t) = \max\limits_{0\leq\tau\leq t} dd(\tau) \]
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: result]